# Ussd code does not work properly

Tags: java, android, ussd

I have a ussd code on a button.I add CALL_PHONE permissions in manifest.
I use the api (23).
This code does not work properly

Basically what I should do?Thanks.
I have following error:

> ?E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.mahdishekari.mycollectbill, PID: 31738
>                     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{4e2904f 31738:com.mahdishekari.mycollectbill/u0a109} (pid=31738, uid=10109) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2776)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1509)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3958)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3919)
>                         at com.mahdishekari.mycollectbill.ActivityMain$C00661.onClick(ActivityMain.java:78)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21349)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31738 SIG: 9
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'

My code:

```
public class ActivityMain extends ActivityBase {
Button btnLink;
Button btnPayBill;
Button btnRecords;
Button btnScanner;
Button btnSupport;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
DatabaseHelper2 myDbHelper;
TextView tvBillType;
TextView tvPrice;
EditText txtBillID;
EditText txtPayID;
EditText txtPrice;


class C00661 implements OnClickListener {
    C00661() {
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String payID = ActivityMain.this.txtPayID.getText().toString();
        String billID = ActivityMain.this.txtBillID.getText().toString();
        String myID = "124336";
        String price = ActivityMain.this.txtPrice.getText().toString();
        if (billID.length() == 0) {
            ActivityMain.this.showToast("\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0647 \u0642\u0628\u0636 \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a");
        } else if (payID.length() == 0) {
            ActivityMain.this.showToast("\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0647 \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062e\u062a \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a");
        } else if (price.length() == 0) {
            ActivityMain.this.showToast("\u0645\u0628\u0644\u063a \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a");
        } else {
            int i;
            int payIdLen = payID.length();
            for (i = 0; i < 13 - payIdLen; i++) {
                payID = "0" + payID;
            }
            int billIdLen = billID.length();
            for (i = 0; i < 13 - billIdLen; i++) {
                billID = "0" + billID;
            }
            Bill entityBillRercord = new Bill();
            entityBillRercord.billId = billID;
            entityBillRercord.createDate = Tools.getDate();
            entityBillRercord.payId = payID;
            entityBillRercord.refId = "";
            entityBillRercord.price = Tools.toInt(price);
            DbBills.insert(entityBillRercord);
            String encodeHash = Uri.encode("#");
            String ussd = "*733*3*2*" + billID + "*" + payID + "*" + encodeHash;
            ActivityMain.this.startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)),1);
        }
    }
}


class Scanner implements OnClickListener {
    Scanner() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnReadBarcode) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(ActivityMain.this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }
}


class C00683 implements OnClickListener {
    C00683() {
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivitySupport.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    }
}


class C00694 implements OnClickListener {
    C00694() {
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "\u0646\u0631\u0645 \u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u0631 \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0642\u0628\u0636");
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "\u0646\u0631\u0645 \u0627\u0641\u0632\u0627\u0631 \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0642\u0628\u0636\n\r\u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062e\u062a \u0631\u0627\u062d\u062a \u0648 \u0622\u0633\u0627\u0646 \u06a9\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0642\u0628\u0648\u0636 \u0645\u062c\u0647\u0632 \u0628\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0631\u06a9\u062f \u062e\u0648\u0627\u0646\n\r http://yealame.ir/upload/allbills.apk");
        ActivityMain.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share"));
    }
}


class C00705 implements OnClickListener {
    C00705() {
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityRecords.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    }
}


class C00716 implements TextWatcher {
    C00716() {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String payID = ActivityMain.this.txtPayID.getText().toString();
        String price = "";
        if (payID.length() != 0) {
            int i;
            int payIdLen = payID.length();
            for (i = 0; i < 13 - payIdLen; i++) {
                payID = "0" + payID;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                price = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(price)).append(String.valueOf(payID.charAt(i))).toString();
            }
            price = String.valueOf(Tools.toInt(price));
            ActivityMain.this.txtPrice.setText(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(price)).append("00").toString());
            ActivityMain.this.tvPrice.setText("\u0645\u0628\u0644\u063a \u0642\u0628\u0636: " + price + "00 \u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646");
        }
    }
}


class C00727 implements TextWatcher {
    C00727() {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String billID = ActivityMain.this.txtBillID.getText().toString();
        int billIdLen = billID.length();
        if (billIdLen != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 13 - billIdLen; i++) {
                billID = "0" + billID;
            }
            ActivityMain.this.setBillIcon(Tools.getBillIcon(billID));
        }
    }
}


class C00738 implements Runnable {
    C00738() {
    }

    public void run() {
        ActivityMain.this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
}

public ActivityMain() {
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setFont(findViewById(R.id.llMain));
    loadDb();
    this.btnPayBill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);
    this.btnScanner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadBarcode);
    this.txtPayID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPayID);
    this.txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    this.txtBillID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBillID);
    this.tvPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBillPrice);
    this.tvBillType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBillType);
    this.btnRecords = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecords);
    this.btnLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLink);
    this.btnSupport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSupport);
    setListeners();
}

private void loadDb() {
    this.myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper2(this);
    try {
        this.myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    try {
        this.myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
    }
    BaseDataLayer.db = this.myDbHelper.getDB();
}

private void setListeners() {
    this.btnPayBill.setOnClickListener(new C00661());
    this.btnScanner.setOnClickListener(new Scanner());
    this.btnSupport.setOnClickListener(new C00683());
    this.btnLink.setOnClickListener(new C00694());
    this.btnRecords.setOnClickListener(new C00705());
    this.txtPayID.addTextChangedListener(new C00716());
    this.txtBillID.addTextChangedListener(new C00727());
}

private void setBillIcon(int billType) {
    switch (billType) {
        case CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY /*1*/:
            this.tvBillType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._bill_1_waterpng);
        case CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER /*2*/:
            this.tvBillType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._bill_2_electric);
        case TransportMediator.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD /*3*/:
            this.tvBillType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._bill_3_gas);
        case TransportMediator.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY /*4*/:
            this.tvBillType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._bill_4_tel);
        default:
            this.tvBillType.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        int contentsLen = scanContent.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26 - contentsLen; i++) {
            scanContent = "0" + scanContent;
        }
        if (scanContent != null) {
            String txtBillID = scanContent.substring(0, 13);
            String txtPayID = scanContent.substring(18);
            this.txtBillID.setText(txtBillID);
            this.txtPayID.setText(txtPayID);
            this.btnPayBill.setActivated(true);
        }
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}


public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "\u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u062e\u0631\u0648\u062c \u062f\u0648\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u06a9\u0644\u06cc\u062f \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06af\u0634\u062a \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0632\u0646\u06cc\u062f", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new ActivityMain.C00738(), 2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the permissions under the right node? Please add the manifest to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I don't know.I add my manifest.please help me.

Comment: It look OK, I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In android > 23 you must check permission at runtime

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But how? Please more guidance.

Comment: @Mahdi follow suggested link above

Answer (score 0):

In the *Manifest* you have declared that you will be requesting those permissions from the user. But, you must understand that you haven't actually obtained those permissions just by declaring them in the *Manifest*. You need to *Request* for those permissions during runtime.

> Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. So even if the app used the camera yesterday, it can't assume it still has that permission today.

Source: [Official Website](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

I haven't gone through your code completely. However, with regards to solving the error you have posted, the solution is pretty simple. All you need to do is to ask for *android.permission.CALL_PHONE* during runtime.

The best guide would probably be the [official website](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). It's just a 10-minute read.